# GCP App Engine dispatch.yaml for dotnet core webapi and angular ui

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I have default service with URL as "https://myprojectid.uc.r.appspot.com" and then I have .net core webapi deployed with service named as "mywebapi-poc" and accessible using "https://mywebapi-poc-dot-myprojectid.uc.r.appspot.com"

now I want to create route using dispatch.yaml something like this. "https://myprojectid.uc.r.appspot.com/mywebapi-poc" and "https://myprojectid.uc.r.appspot.com/mywebui-poc" which can route all web api requests to mywebapi-poc service and all web ui requests to mywebui-poc service

How can I make it work ?

```
dispatch:
  - url: "myprojectid.uc.r.appspot.com/"
    service: default

  - url: "myprojectid.uc.r.appspot.com/mywebapi-poc/*"
    service: mywebapi-poc
  
  - url: "myprojectid.uc.r.appspot.com/mywebui-poc/*"
    service: mywebui-poc
```

After doing this when I call it like this https://myprojectid.uc.r.appspot.com/mywebapi-poc/api/v1/WeatherForecast

I get 404

Similar is the case for angular web UI. First index.html page loads but after that subsequent angular app file doesn't load. For example https://myprojectid.uc.r.appspot.com/mywebui-poc/ loads index.html with 200 response but https://myprojectid.uc.r.appspot.com/mywebui-poc/main.js doesn't load and I get 404.
Please note that I had path issue earlier with "/" so I replaced it in index.html with "/mywebui-poc/"

With "/" I can make individual UI service working with https://mywebui-poc-dot-myprojectid.uc.r.appspot.com

Answer (score 0):

App engine writes dispatching rules in the priority of the order mentioned in the dispatch.yaml. In the documentation they state that

> Dispatch rules are order dependent, and only the first rule that
> matches a URL will be applied.

In your case the first routing rule in dispatch.yaml points to the "default" service and that specific part of the domain (`myprojectid.uc.r.appspot.com/`) is common across all the routes. So which ever URL you try to hit with this domain will route to default service. Instead write your dispatch.yaml as below and it should work

```
dispatch:
  - url: "myprojectid.uc.r.appspot.com/mywebapi-poc/*"
    service: mywebapi-poc
  
  - url: "myprojectid.uc.r.appspot.com/mywebui-poc/*"
    service: mywebui-poc
```

Anything that is omitted in the dispatch.yaml routes will automatically route to default service

Comment: I was able to resolve using this. - url: "*/mywebapi-poc/*"
    service: mywebapi-poc